# No items returned when using "relevance" to order results when searching CommentThreads

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Update:** It was a bug, now fixed.

Searching youtube comments API with `searchTerms=someKeywords` and `order=relevance` doesn't return results, but when setting `order=time` it works, any idea why?

Sample API Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?videoId=pvyfddIFsVA&searchTerms=Google&order=relevance&part=snippet&key=[YOUR API KEY]
```

Returned Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/6qokcCVLNOLwE7dOHNSTr30kECQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },
 "items": []
}
```

From the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list):

The **order** parameter specifies the order in which the API response should list comment threads. Valid values are:

- `time` - Comment threads are ordered by time. This is the default
  behavior.
- `relevance` - Comment threads are ordered by relevance.

It seems that order by `relevance` is not working.

Comment: Can you use the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list) for replicate the request you're using?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I did, if you take any video on Youtube and set order by relevance you will get empty response. It's either a bug or deliberately disabled by Google but no update in the documentation or anywhere else.

Comment: user5513314, it would be helpful if you add the request demo you're using...

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Question updated.

Comment: have you checkec if there is a issue tracker related to this problem? if you haven't check, I recomment to do so. [Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). This is a bug, IMHO.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave yeah that's what I thought, I've reported the issue through the link you provided, post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I found this question, because I experienced something similar. I haven't been searching comments, but returning all instead. When I ordered by `time`, it worked just fine. But when I ordered by `relevance`, it returned just about 15% of all the comments (~5k of the ~30k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug, the best option in this case is report the bug by creating a new entry in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803).

This is the [Issue Tracker entry created by the OP](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128740214).